# Postscript parser - add hyperlinks to text

Tags: adobe, postscript

I need to take a list of questions on a pdf, and hyperlink the answer to each question.

I currently have converted the pdf file to postscript. However, postscript is a very complicated language to programmatically hyperlink each question of the format `Question #i:` to a link `example.com/answers/i/`. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

PostScript isn't merely complicated, its a complete programming language. This means that the way your answer is expressed in the program is entirely arbitrary.

Assuming you are using the same conversion process each time, you can probably assume that its deterministic in its behaviour (ie it converts the same input to the same output every time), in which case you can probably look for the result in the output.

But basically, you're on your own here, there isn't some magic solution I can give you.

I'd suggest that you're doping it wrong anyway. PostScript isn't PDF, and it doesn't have any concept of a hyperlink. So this suggests to me that you intend to use a pdfmark extension operator, and then pass the resulting PostScript back through a Distiller-like application in order to get a PDF back out again.

Converting to PostScript and back to PDF really just confuses the issue. Assuming that the PDF is a form (again, by implication from the question and answer format) you can extract the form field readily enough from the PDF file directly. Then you can replace it with a /Link annotation.

In short, don't do this by going to PostScript and back, do it all in PDF.

If there's a reason why you can't do this, then you're going to have to explain it.

Comment: The pdf is a textbook, complete with images, annotations and lots of information. What tool should I use to extract the pdf?

Comment: OK so its not a form, so you can't simply modify the form field. Since I haven't seen the PDF there isn't any further advice I can offer you. I don't think it likely that you can programatically locate content which is not obviously marked out in some way and modify it. I'm even more certain you can't do it by creating a PostScritp file from the PDF. You need to inspect the PDF content, find some way to identify the content you want to modify and then alter the PDF content. No idea how you're going to do that.